# Использование кириллицы в модуле angular qrcode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Возникла следующая проблема, при подключении модуля генерации qr кода, https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode к проекту, что бы не делал при вводе русских букв получаемый qr-код интерпретируется в неправильной кодировке.

Файл js сохранен в кодировке utf-8.
Пример:
"Привет мир" получается как "?@825B <8@".

Декодер говорит что это **7-bit ASCII → KOI8-U + KOI8-R → ISO-8859-5**, но как так получается не пойму. Пытался сохранять файл в разных кодировках на выходе получаю - "??????????".

В демо примере к модулю, с русскими буквами проблем нет, подскажите в каком направлении копать.

Пример кода такой:

```
<div class="block-qr">
    <qrcode version="8" error-correction-level="Medium" size="400" data="{{vm.data}}" href="{{var}}" download></qrcode>
</div>
<form class="block-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Заголовок</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Заголовок" ng-model="vm.title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Организация</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Организация" ng-model="vm.org">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>Телефон</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Телефон" ng-model="vm.phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="exampleInputEmail1" ng-model="vm.emails">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Сайт</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Сайт" ng-model="vm.site">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.concat()">Сгенерировать</button>
</form>
```

И контроллер:

```
function concat() {
        vm.data = 'Title: ' + vm.title + '\nOrg: ' + vm.org + '\nPhone number: ' + vm.phone + '\nEmail: ' + vm.emails + '\n ' + vm.site;            
        return vm.data;
    }
```

Собственно для латиницы никаких проблем, все замечательно работает.

Comment: А как вы проверяете данные в `qr` коде?

Comment: Проверять данные проблемы не составляет, достаточно много приложений на тел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы видимо не подключили все необходимые скрипты.

А именно поддержку **UTF-8**.

Если посмотреть [пример использования](http://monospaced.github.io/angular-qrcode/), то мы увидим, что там подключается скрипт http://monospaced.github.io/bower-qrcode-generator/js/qrcode_UTF8.js.

Посмотрите пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/L9tqocmq/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['monospaced.qrcode'])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kazuhikoarase/qrcode-generator/master/js/qrcode.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kazuhikoarase/qrcode-generator/master/js/qrcode_UTF8.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode/master/angular-qrcode.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <label>Сайт</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Сайт" ng-model="vm.site">
    <qrcode data="{{vm.site}}"></qrcode>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, сейчас проверю.

Comment: Слона я и не заметил, спасибо, при установке через bower устанавливаются 2 папки angular-qrcode и qrcode-generator, собственно я подключил скрипт из первой папки все заработало но без поддержки латиницы, добавив оставшиеся скрипты все стало работать как нужно.